# Is Selenium not suitable for Salesforce Velocity application?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, salesforce-lightning

We are using the Salesforce application with velocity in our Org.
While trying to perform test automation for the application, we got comments that Selenium is not suitable for velocity.
But when I try to search in the web, I don't see any issues/restrictions with selenium.
Can anyone tried using selenium for automating Salesforce Velocity? If so what are the pros/cons please.